# Solar panel help

Tags: solar-cell, charge, controller

I already have a solar charge controller connected to my solar panels protecting the attached batteries from overcharging.

However I'd like to charge a second battery bank without connecting it up to the first battery bank.
Are there any solar charge controllers that either have the option to charge two battery Banks independently or is there a way to use the same controller to charge both battery Banks while preventing the voltage to the second battery Bank from going back out into the charge controller and first bank?

Maybe a resistor of some kind?

I know it sounds weird but I'm basically looking for a check valve that will prevent the energy from going back through the solar charge controller to the first bank.

It's a 60 amp 12 volt system that I'm working with.

Thanks for your help

Comment: A block diagram would help explain your text. But from what I can work out, what's wrong with a diode?

Comment: Have you looked for any controllers that can handle 2 battery banks?

Comment: There are commercial products available for the very situation you describe. A poor mans version of it is a Schottky diode rated for your full current. Make sure both batteries are charged up to the same voltage before connecting them.

Comment: Thanks all I have looked for controllers that can handle to battery Banks but was not able to find anything reasonably cost effective.  If there's any way somebody could help me size a diode and I might need that would be great.  Battery I would be using is 14.8 volts with a 27 amp initial current

Comment: 27 A is a lot. If you can't find a 30 V 40 A diode, feel free to parallel several 30 V diodes to give enough current capability.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. _Schottky_ diodes. You can't successfully parallel regular silicon diodes, only Schottky diodes.